# Looping through commands' results, KSH script

Tags: ksh, string

I'd like to put two strings in two different variables. 
Let's take a small example.

after a simple grep, I got this :

```
$ grep nl.*acc.*bas :
ABAS01=...
ABAS02=...
```

I'd like to have two variables, one containing ABAS01, and the other containing ABAS02.

How can I do this ? I guess a loop can be used to go through all the results from my query, then I could do a `cut -d= -f1` to retrieve the name of the variables.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's AT&T or `zsh` implementations of `ksh`:

```
cmd | { IFS== read -r var1 x && IFS== read -r var2 x; }
```